# Extract a value from a cell if it matches a list of characters

Tags: excel

I'm trying to extract a word from a sentence if it starts with one of the following letters.Dell** or Samsung** or Apple**. The position of the words may vary in the cell.

A1:  Dell2622 Retail34792 Lenovo StoreQuantity4
  A2:  Retail9858 Qty8 Samsung783546 Android
  A3:  Retail21512 Apple3411 StoreQty15 Macintosh

I am trying to use the following formula to extract the Dell** or Samsung** or Apple** if it's present int the cell.

```
  =MID(A1, SEARCH({"Dell","Samsung","Apple"},A1), SEARCH(" ",A1, SEARCH({"Dell","Samsung","Apple"},A1))- SEARCH({"Dell","Samsung","Apple"},A1))
```

It works for the cell A1, but everything else returns #VALUE!. I guess it doesn't recognize that i want it to check for either or and extract either or. The result I'm trying to achieve is:

A1:  Dell2622
  A2:  Samsung783546
  A3:  Apple3411

Later on i may need to add more things to search for, so I'm trying to keep it easily modifiable. I guess since it finds the first instance, then it's just a matter of tweaking something to ensure that if it didn't find the first value it looks for second, etc.

Comment: If you always only need the second string, you can use this formula: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",255)),255,255))`

Comment: Sorry, the positioning may vary as well as length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a data setup similar to the picture below, with your strings in column A, the formula in column B, and the words to look for in column D:

[image: tigeravatar example]

The formula in cell B2 and copied down is:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,MIN(INDEX(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,A2&$D$2:$D$4),)),255)," ",REPT(" ",255)),255))
```

And per your request to not use a range reference and instead have the list of words directly in the formula:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,MIN(INDEX(SEARCH({"Dell","Samsung","Apple"},A3&{"Dell","Samsung","Apple"}),)),255)," ",REPT(" ",255)),255))
```

Comment: This looks great, but is there a way to specify the words in D column inside of the formula instead? Also, not sure why, stretching formula to entire worksheet doesn't work, it only works with first three results. Even if i copy the first three cells down, i get a #value!.

Comment: Ah, that's because the formula as is originally would need to be array-entered.  I have edited it so include the `INDEX` function so that it treats itself as an array formula without you array-entering the formula.  It should work for you now.  As for the "type the values into the formula instead of using cell references", I have edited the answer to include that as well.  Just remember that if you add items, you'll need to add it in both places.

Comment: This is simply incredible. Thanks a lot. Exactly what i imagined, but better.